# Where to host javascript Closed Source front-end library for distribution?

Tags: javascript, firebase, hosting, web-hosting, firebase-hosting

I have a JavaScript library I would like to distribute to clients for using through script tag on their websites.

My project is not open-source so I cannot use open-source services like jsDelivr.

I was thinking about using Firebase (I hope they have good CDN) hosting where I would upload my script, which will be then directly accessed by other websites. Is this a viable solution or is there other/better service for this use-case?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Hosting has no access control on deployed files. That means that, like on any public CDN, anyone who knows the URL of the file can access it.

If you don't want to share the code publicly, you should probably not put the file on any CDN. Distributing the code directly to your customers would be the most logical alternative. They would then include the code directly into their build process, instead of pulling it live from the CDN.

But if you want to pull it from the CDN, the best you can do is use an unguessable URL. Typically something very long and random like `http://mycdn.com/path/to/file/unguessableFDJIQRE(@#(U/index.js`. This ensure that random users are unlikely to ever find the file, and only users who know if its existence can get it. That said, here too it remains that anyone who knows the URL of the file can access it.

Comment: It should be as easy as possible to include this code in client website so I guess the only way is using script tag with src attribute.
But is it even needed to obfuscate the URL when anyone can see that link in the client's source?

Comment: It wasn't clear to me who the users of the final produce will be. If the library is targeted to be used in public websites, and you want those to use it from the CDN, the while approach seems like a waste of energy indeed and you're probably better of just obfuscating the code as @eldar's answer suggest.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few strategies here:

1. Uglify/minimize your JS script. Users will still be able to read it, but it will be hard because all of the variable names will be replaced with not human readable names. That said, it's definitely possible to reverse engineer an uglified script.
2. Use a JS obfuscator, which will go a step further and rewrite your code to be almost indecipherable.
3. Set up a static webserver that requires an authentication token to serve up your script. Unless your clients pass a valid auth header, they'll get a 404.

Comment: I was planning to uglify the code, but I didn't think about using obfuscator, that's a good point.

But is generic website-hosting (like Firebase) suitable for hosting script like this? Or should I use some different service?

Comment: I don't have much experience with Firebase, but probably? Any service that lets you host and serve static files publicly would work. What kind of traffic load are you expecting? If you need to serve 100+ copies of this script or more per minute, I would go with a CDN, or something that behaves like it. AWS S3 is very cheap and handles both static file hosting and acts like a CDN.